# How to get multiple pages in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

This is so confusing. I going to need *alot* more pages in my Android app. But I don't see where I'd do that.... This is what my Eclipse looks like:
http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/4227/unled2qir.png

Comment: What are "pages" and what does this have to do with Android?

Comment: Please read the doc, especially the part about Activities. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'page' in your image is a graphical representation of a 'layout' file for a 'View' although in your case possibly the 'layout' for an `Activity`.

To add another, in the 'Package Explorer' pane, right-click your 'GameNetwork' project icon and select New -> Android XML File. Then when the dialog appears, select the 'Layout' radio-button under "What sort of resource would you like to create?" and give it a filename in the "File" edit box such as 'new-layout.xml'.

Comment: Thank you so much! (Sorry, I'm a noob. I didn't know what else to call it besides a "page")

Comment: Glad to help - it took me a while to work out how to do a lot of things in eclipse. Check the link alextsc added as comment to your question - it explains Activities very well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new xml file for each 'page' as you call them.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html